# Is Java foreach loop an overkill for repeated execution

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, foreach, garbage-collection

I agree foreach loop reduces typing and good for readability.

A little backup, I work on low latency application development and receive 1Million packets to process per second. Iterating through a million packets and sending this information across to its listeners. I was using foreach loop to iterate through the set of listeners.

Doing profiling i figured there are a lot of **Iterator objects** created to execute foreach loop. Converting foreach loop to index based foreach I observed a huge drop in the number of objects created there by reducing no. of GC's and increasing application throughput.

**Edit**: (Sorry for confusion, making this Q more clearer)
For example i have list of listeners(fixed size) and i loop through this forloop a million times a second.  Is foreach an overkill in java?

Example:

```
for(String s:listOfListeners)
{
   // logic
}
```

compared to

```
for (int i=0;i<listOfListeners.size();i++)
{
   // logic
}
```

Profiled screenshot for the code

```
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 1_000_000; cnt++)
{
    for (String string : list_of_listeners)
    {
         //No Code here 
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Good on you for profiling, but you should really reword your question so people do not misinterpret it - you are calling this loop 1,000,000 times (number of packets) on a relatively small number of listeners (list.size)

Comment: @AK4749: So "Size of list is around a million objects streaming in" is a complete red herring?

Comment: @AK4749 *Iterating through a million packets and sending this information across to its listeners*. This means a large list of packets and a small list of listeners (relatively).

Comment: @JonSkeet exactly. 100% misleading

Comment: @maba isn't that what I said? I was just clearing up the confusion for others so they won't make the same mistake. I would have edited the question myself, but it's so unclear that I'm not 100% sure that is his intent

Comment: @srujan `foreach (listener : list_of_listener)` -> call the other for loop with `list = 1 000 000 Strings`?

Comment: Sorry corrected the question.

Comment: @AK4749 I though you said *calling this loop 1,000,000 times*. I mean that the loop is called as many times as number of listeners. Which means it will not create 1,000,000 iterators but number-of-listeners iterators.

Comment: @All Jon Skeet confirmed there will be an Iterator created every time it's asked for. So calling the foreach a Million times would create a Million Iterators.

Comment: Added screenshot which might be helpful.

Comment: @srujangulla: No, your screenshot just shows that there are a lot of objects. It doesn't say anything about the *impact* of those objects on the system, and that's the important point.

Comment: @JonSkeet Frequent young generation collection's which I see in the log. I started to use regular for loop which reduced the no. of young generation collections. So I am good over here. On a side note I was going thru your "In Depth C#" book. I am was wondering is there any plans of you writing a book on Java. I am a great fan of your posts and a book on java will be fantastic.

Comment: @srujangulla: No plans, I'm afraid. I have a great deal more to write about C#, when I get the time :)

Comment: @JonSkeet hmm.. not a problem.. please keep this great sharing of knowledge.. appreciate it.. please consider writing a java book in future if you can. I will be the first to buy it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT: Answering the vastly different question of:

> For example i have list of listeners(fixed size) and i loop through this forloop a million times a second. Is foreach an overkill in java?

That depends - does your profiling actually show that the extra allocations are *significant*? The Java allocator and garbage collector can do a *lot* of work per second.

To put it another way, your steps should be:

1. Set performance goals alongside your functional requirements
2. Write the simplest code you can to achieve your functional requirements
3. Measure whether that code meets the functional requirements
4. If it doesn't:

   - Profile to work out where to optimize
   - Make a change
   - Run the tests again to see whether they make a significant difference in your meaningful metrics (number of objects allocated probably isn't a meaningful metric; number of listeners you can handle probably is)
   - Go back to step 3.

*Maybe* in your case, the enhanced for loop is significant. I wouldn't assume that it is though - nor would I assume that the creation of a million objects per second is significant. I would measure the *meaningful* metrics before and after... and make sure you have concrete performance goals before you do anything else, as otherwise you won't know when to stop micro-optimizing.

---

> Size of list is around a million objects streaming in.

So you're creating *one* iterator object, but you're executing your loop body a million times.

> Doing profiling i figured there are a lot of Iterator objects created to execute foreach loop.

Nope? Only a *single* iterator object should be created. [As per the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:

```
    for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
        VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier =
            (TargetType) #i.next();
        Statement
    }
```

As you can see, that calls the `iterator()` method *once*, and then calls `hasNext()` and `next()` on it on each iteration.

Do you think that extra object allocation will actually hurt your performance significantly?

How much do you value readability over performance? I take the approach of using the enhanced for loop wherever it helps readability, until it proves to be a performance problem - and my personal experience is that it's *never* hurt performance significantly in anything I've written. That's not to say that would be true for all applications, but the *default* position should be to only use the less readable code after proving it will improve things significantly.

Comment: Um, well I could be wrong, but I think most people are not reading his unclear question very carefully. He is, in fact, calling this loop 1000000 times, because the loop is just for the set of listeners.

Comment: @Jonskeet Let me change this a little bit. Iteration of foreach is in a method say callForEach(List l) and I pass the list as an argument. Elements are added to this list constantly and every addition of elements to this list would call the method callForEach(List l) In this case doesnt it create an iterator object for call?

Comment: @AK4749: I've read it carefully several times, and it's still incredibly unclear to me. But if the size of the list is 1 million objects, then it's still unlikely that when iterating over that, the iterator created will be the bottleneck.

Comment: @srujangulla: Don't add a comment - edit your question, which is incredibly unclear. And don't *describe* your code - include it in the question. But you need to understand that executing a single enhanced for loop will only create a single iterator.

Comment: Yeah, he uses "list" twice - one for the packets and in the code for the listeners. But yeah definitely, that is the most important point from which his answer could be derived either way

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated the Question. I have to check the source code but Is an iterator a singleton object for a given list? Does changes to the list create a unique iterator object?

Comment: @srujangulla: No, an iterator is created every time it's *asked* for. It's not created when the list changes - only when you iterate. See my edit at the top of my answer.

Comment: By the way, isn't `List#get` vs `Iterator#hasNext` + `Iterator#next` worth comparing as well? I've always thought that the abovementioned comparison result is dependent upon implementation-specific details. Isn't *that* the bottleneck in lists of high volume?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the updated answer. Every time i loop through a list if its creating an Iterator object then its definitely affects the performance. I am doing a ParallelGC so StopTheWorld pauses are significant for processing a Feed Handler on MarketData application.

Comment: @srujangulla: Well these should all be very short-lived objects, so I'd expect them to be collected easily. Again, don't *assume* that it'll impact performance significantly - *test*. If it's as significant as you expect it to be, it should be really easy to spot the difference outside a profiler.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure. will do that. If JVM's generational memory allocation is not done correctly it might be a problem but definitely testing would tell the answer since each application behaves differently. Thanks for all the input. Its much clear for me now.

Answer (score 6):

The "foreach" loop creates just one `Iterator` object, while the second loop creates none. If you are executing many, many separate loops that execute just a few times each, then yes, "foreach" may be unnecessarily expensive. Otherwise, this is micro-optimizing.

Comment: Yes, i believe actually his use-case is the second one, where there are 1,000,000 calls to the relatively small for loop. I believe his question is quite unclear in this regard

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The question has changed so much since I wrote my answer that I'm not sure what I'm answering at the moment.

Looking up stuff with `list.get(i)` can actually be a lot slower if it's a *linked list*, since for each lookup, it has to traverse the list, while the iterator remembers the position.

Example:

```
list.get(0) will get the first element
list.get(1) will first get the first element to find pointer to the next
list.get(2) will first get the first element, then go to the second and then to the third
etc.
```

So to do a full loop, you're actually looping over elements in this manner:

```
0
0->1
0->1->2
0->1->2->3
etc.
```

Comment: That's assuming a *linked* list... I don't see any evidence of that.

Comment: @JonSkeet true, should have specified that, fixed now. OP mentioned a list w/o specifying the implementation used.

Comment: Yes, and in my experience `ArrayList` is used more often in Java than `LinkedList`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, in my experience as well. Just thought I'd point it out, could've been the reason for the big difference. I've made that mistake myself before, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you should worry about the effectiveness here.

Most of time is consumed by your actual application logic (in this case - by what you do inside the loop).

So, I would not worry about the price you pay for convenience here.

Comment: While this is true in 90% of the cases, I don't know if you can say this without knowing the application logic - heap based memory allocation has large performance drawbacks when being called in code hotspots

Answer (score 0):

Is this comparison even fair ? You are comparing using an `Iterator` Vs using `get(index)`

Furthermore, each loop would only create one additional `Iterator`. Unless the `Iterator` is itself inefficient for some reason, you should see comparable performance.